# How to build an Angular 2 + NodeJS Web App?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, deployment, mean-stack

This is really simple I know but this is my very first time working with `nodejs`.

I have a `Angular 2` app with and have the `Angular CLI` installed for working with my app.

I can successfully build the client side by running `ng build`.

I have since added a server.js and server folder (containing api routes) to the root of my app to run a `nodejs` back end:

**Current Folder Structure**

[image: Root]

I can run the server side along with the client locally by running `ng build` and then `node server`.

Running `ng build` only builds the client side and puts it into the `dist` folder ready for deployment but how can I do the same the server.js and server folder and add it to the dist folder so the client can communicate with the server?

There are so many tools out there such as Grunt, Gulp Webpack and Browserify but I have no idea where to start.

I know that `package.json` plays a role in how our app is configured so here it is:

```
    {
  "name": "Portfolio",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ng build && node server.js",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.8",
    "angular2-google-maps": "^0.17.0",
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.16.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "nodemailer": "^3.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.8",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.35",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.43",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.5",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.1",
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^2.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-ts": "^6.0.0-beta.11",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.5.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.1",
    "ts-node": "2.1.0",
    "tslint": "^4.4.2",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  }
}
```

**Questions**

- How can I build my server code and bundle it into the dist folder ready for deployment?
- What is the most common method for achieving this?

Comment: Sorry I meant 'build' as in put the server code into the dist folder along with the client

Answer (score 0):

your API and your angular 2 app are supposed to be independent of each other, where your API runs on itself and is contacted by your Angular 2 app,
2 different deploys, they shouldn't go in the same build.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the 2 in the same folder for them to communicate; make sure `server.js` responds with AngularJS' index file for any route that you haven't used for your api. E.g: if `server.js` (within the root folder, i.e  `/server.js`) is listenning on port 8080:

```
// /server.js
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var path = require('path');

const appRoute = require("./routes/app"); // This route redirects all other requests to angular's index

//View Engine
app.set('view engine', "ejs");
app.engine("html", require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));

//Set static folder, since there are AngularJS resources
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist")));

//app.get("/api/...", apiRoute....); Here you put routes for your api
app.get('/*', appRoute.index); // This route redirects all other requests to angular's index


const PORT = process.env.port || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Running on the port " +PORT);
});
```

In `appRoute` (stored at `/routes/app.js`) you then need to render `/dist/index.html` provided this is your AngularJS index file.

```
// /routes/app.js
var express = require("express");
var path = require('path');

exports.index = (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/..', 'dist/index.html'));
};
```

`package.json` can point to the starting scripts of your node server and AngularJS app but the logic in `server.js` will make the link with the 2 fronts of the application, i.e. `server.js` has to respond at some point by rendering `/dist/index.html`. Please watch out for the paths if you refer to this example.